# Execute C# method / function from trigger in SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, triggers

I'm working on a project which requires execution of C# method / function (coded on a web page) using a trigger or stored procedure in SQL Server.

I found this [Execute-NET-Code-under-SQL-Server](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19954/Execute-NET-Code-under-SQL-Server)

But as stated on this link, I have to change the database property `TRUSTWORTHY` to `ON`.

Is there any way I can do this without changing database properties?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Almost certainly not.

Comment: You most definitely *don't* have to change this database property. You need it only when your assembly is unsigned and needs to access external resources

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Since OP need to somehow invoke external webpage (if I got his point correctly) - he need TRUSTWORTHY ON and assembly with EXTERNAL_ACCESS permission. The only alternative - is running external program, as I've stated in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you don't want (or can) use SQLCLR - you can create some standalone console application containing all c# code you need and then execute this application with some parameters using [xp_cmdshell](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175046.aspx).

But note: xp_cmdshell is disabled by default, you have to enable it using

```
EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1
```

Since xp_cmdshell is server option - you don't need to change database properties, but you have to change server options to enable it in the case it is disabled. Choose yourself - what to change. ;)

Comment: This is far worse from a security viewpoint than changing a database option - `xp_cmdshell` can easily execute malicious scripts using SQL Server's service account

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to execute the external code synchronously? In other words, must the external code start and run to completion before your trigger ends?

If the answer is yes, then I suggest changing your design.  You're using triggers incorrectly and making whatever DML operation fires the trigger tremendously slow.

Assuming the answer is no then, you have options to queue up whatever work needs to be done and have that work executed asynchronously.  For example, your trigger could create a record in a work-queue table when it needs this external code to run.  Some other process (e.g. a scheduled task, SQL Agent, something in your application, SQL Server Broker) can monitor this table for new records and fire off the appropriate calls as needed.